# Is " char * p1;  p1 = str; " the same as " char * p1 = str; " in c++?

Tags: c++, pointers

I would just like to know whether the following statements are the same:

```
char str[80];    
char *p1;
p1 = str;
```

and

```
char str[80];    
char *p1 = str;
```

Thanks

Comment: The same in which way? Syntactically, obviously not. Standard-/grammar-wise, no (the first is assignment, the second is initialization). Observationally, yes.

Comment: Did you notice any behavioral differences? Or are you looking for other differences?

Comment: Syntactically they are , of course, different, but I wanted to know whether they do the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. In both cases an implicit array-to-pointer conversion takes place, and the pointer becomes initialised to the address of the first element of the array.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, the statements are the same.

Comment: Wow! lightening fast. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

In the first example, the value of str is assigned to the variable p1 (basic char to char assignment).

In the second example, you are declaring p1 as a pointer pointing to the value of str.